# Tabula.read_pdf - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, tabula-py

may I know why I will get `IndexError` when running the below code

```
import tabula
df = tabula.read_pdf("123.pdf", pages='all')[0]
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: you have an empty list.  So the index is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

because the list that is returned to you is of course empty, which is like `[]`